# MySQL: SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, title, url
FROM stats;
```

My goal is to select one row for each distinct `ip`, along with `title` and `url`; however I find when I add the `title` and `url` fields to my query it shows me all rows.

#### Sample Data

```
ip          title      url
---------------------------
127.0.0.1   title      url
127.0.0.2   title      url
127.0.0.1   difftitle  url
```

#### Result I would like

```
ip          title      url
---------------------------
127.0.0.1   title      url
127.0.0.2   title      url
```

Comment: May be more easily done with a server script.

Comment: Not quite clear provide some sample data and expected result out of it into the question.

Comment: if you have two different title or url with the same IP, which of them you want select?

Comment: @vathek the first occurrence

Comment: Is there any primary key in the table ?

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll The first occurence? Apart from the fact, that there's no "first" in a relational database, unless you define it with another column, this is very confusing. I thought, you want the rows where ip is unique? What's the desired result from your sample data?

Comment: What data would you like to select from the sample data you have provided?

Comment: @Eilidh: 127.0.0.1 title url and
127.0.0.2 title url

Comment: So you only want one `title` and `url` per `ip`? 

What determines *which* `title` and `url`? Or do you not care which one is shown?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is a query like this -

```
SELECT 
    ip,
    title,
    url
FROM 
    stats
GROUP BY 
    ip
```

`GROUP BY` is similar to `DISTINCT` - it means that all results will be grouped by `ip`, so it will only show one row of results for each distinct `ip`. However, nothing determines *which* record will be returned (e.g. which `title` and `url` will be shown).

There is no 'first' entry in the database - a relational database has no 'order' as such, unless you choose to order by a field.

Comment: title, url needs to go in Group by as well or needs to be put in some aggregate function like max() in Select